# Code Behind on hidden HTML DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have a hidden search menu on my navigation that I click to display it.  This loads a few different dropdown lists.  I can get the lists to populate with the all of the code right in the ASP tag, but I cannot get it to work via code behind.  Currently I have it in page load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ddl1.DataSource = database;
ddl1.DataTextField = "Name";
ddl1.DataValueField = "Name";
ddl1.DataBind();
ddl2.DataSource = database;
ddl2.DataTextField = "ID";
ddl2.DataValueField = "ID";
ddl2.DataBind();
ddl3.DataSource = database;
ddl3.DataTextField = "effect";
ddl3.DataValueField = "effect";
ddl3.DataBind();
}
```

in my ASPX page

```
<div class="form-control-custom">
<form id="ListForm" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="database" runat="server" ConnectionString="<StringIsInHere>"</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: What you mean not working, is the data bind not working or dropdown list post back not working?

Comment: Correct, its not binding the data to the dropdowns

Comment: Looks like you are missing `SelectCommand="">` on `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="database" runat="server" ConnectionString="<StringIsInHere>"</asp:SqlDataSource>`. So it would be something like `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="database" SelectCommand="Select * From YourTable Where ...." runat="server" ConnectionString="<StringIsInHere>"</asp:SqlDataSource>`

Comment: Oops thats my fault, I do have the SelectCommand there SelectCommand="SELECT [Name] FROM [database] ORDER BY [Name]" , will I need a sqldatasource for each column?

Comment: Yes, you do need all those columns in the select statement.

Comment: `SelectCommand="SELECT Name, ID, Effect FROM [database] ORDER BY [Name]"`

Comment: Still not binding even with it in there with that code or just using the wizard to configure

Comment: When you use the wizard to configure the `sqldatasource`, Visual Studio automatically puts the `SelectCommand` in there.

Comment: Or you can just change the dropdown list in the HTML as `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" DataSourceID="database" DataValueField="Name" DataTextField="Name"></asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: I have gotten it to work with that same exact statement Tumen.  I am still new and hear you can only apply CSS to elements using code behind so I was trying to get it to populate that way.

Comment: Is everything working then? You can apply css to elements in the HTML code using the `CssClass` attribute.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the pageload and check if your datasource get the data you want.